# Why is DocumentFragment cleared after appending

Tags: javascript, documentfragment

The first log returns a full `li` element while the second one returns an empty `DocumentFragment`. Why? I couldn't find any information about that behavior in any documentation.

```js
var main = document.getElementById('main');
var fooTemplate = document.getElementById('my-template');
var foo = fooTemplate.content.cloneNode(true);

console.log(foo);
main.appendChild(foo);
console.log(foo);
```

```html
<template id="my-template">
    <li>foo</li>
</template>

<ul id="main">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 6):

[From the MDN docs on `DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment)

> Various other methods can take a document fragment as an argument (e.g., any `Node` interface methods such as `Node.appendChild` and `Node.insertBefore`), in which case the children of the fragment are appended or inserted, not the fragment itself.

`foo = fooTemplate.content.cloneNode(true)` copies the document fragment to `foo`.

`main.appendChild(foo)` moves the *contents* of the `foo` document fragment into `main`. `foo` remains a document fragment, and all the nodes have moved so it's empty.

If you want to keep a reference to the DOM nodes after appending them, you need to store the `childNodes`, but if you just reference the `nodeList`, it'll be empty, so you'll need to convert it to an `Array`:

```
var nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(foo.childNodes);
console.log(nodes);
main.appendChild(foo);
console.log(nodes);
```

Comment: Well, it still returns the same result…

Comment: @Lithy, oh, i see now. I spoke too soon. `fooTemplate.content.cloneNode(true)` clones the document fragment. Appending the document fragment moves the contents, leaving you with an empty document fragment.

Comment: I think you shouldn't use the term "copy" here. Either they are "moved" or "cloned".

Comment: Isn't there some clean method to simply get a reference to the newly appent node? I am a little bit surprised…

Comment: @Lithy, this is why jQuery is such a popular library.

Comment: @Lithy, If you used appendChild, you can actually get the last child from the node you appended it too. That's is pretty clean as you can put that stuff away in a function. Remember JS is single threaded, so it won't cause any problems. (Except for in NodeJs Maybe, but I'm not sure, and you won't be doing much DOM stuff there anyway.)